# Search files in directories excluding some nested ones

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that searches for files with the .exe extension in a directory except for one of the subdirectories. Can you please tell me how you can add to the list of exclusions, for example, 2 or 3 directories at once?

My script:

```
for /d %%a in (D:\*) do if /i not "%%a"=="D:\1" where /r %%~sa\ *.exe >> d:\%pcname.txt
```

I need something like this:

```
for /d %%a in (D:\*) do if /i not "%%a"=="D:\1", "D:\2" where /r %%~sa\ *.exe >> d:\%pcname.txt
```

Comment: Modify `if /i not "%%a"=="D:\1"` to `if /i not "%%a"=="D:\1" if /i not "%%a"=="D:\2" if /i not "%%a"=="D:\3"`. That should be pretty clear. Or use `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "D:\*" /AD-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /X /G:"D:\Exclusion List.txt"') do %SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R "D:\%%I" *.exe >>"D:\%ComputerName%.txt"` and the file `D:\Exclusion List.txt` contains the names of the directories to exclude without path.

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R "D:\%%I" *.exe` could be replaced by `dir "D:\%%I\*.exe" /A-D /B /S` if there are no files with a file extension starting with `.exe` and having a longer file extension like `.exec`. A file with file name `test.exec` has the short file name `TEST~1.EXE` and the Windows kernel function used by __DIR__ applies a wildcard pattern like `*.exe` on long and short 8.3 file name and returns the long file name if there is a positive match on short name of a file.

Answer (score 0):

The following PowerShell script creates a list of the directories to scan and iterates over it checking for directories not in an exclusion list.

```
$BaseDir = 'C:\src\t'
$FileFilter = '*.xlsx'
$DirExceptions = @('C:\src\t\PSGraph', 'C:\src\t\PSGraph\docs')

$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $BaseDir
$Dirs += Get-Item -Path $BaseDir    # add the base directory to the list

foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {
    if ($Dir.FullName -notin $DirExceptions) {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir -Filter $FileFilter | Select-Object -Property FullName
    }
}
```

If you must run from cmd.exe, either save the script above as Get-Exes.ps1 and use

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File 'Get-Exes.ps1'
```

or the following .bat file script might be used.

```
@powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$BaseDir = 'C:\src\t';" ^
    "$FileFilter = '*.xlsx';" ^
    "$DirExceptions = @('C:\src\t\PSGraph', 'C:\src\t\PSGraph\docs');" ^
    "$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path $BaseDir;" ^
    "$Dirs += Get-Item -Path $BaseDir;" ^
    "foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {" ^
        "if ($Dir.FullName -notin $DirExceptions) {" ^
            "Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Dir.FullName -Filter '*.xlsx' | Select-Object -Property FullName" ^
        "}" ^
    "}"
```